# Deploying ASPNet core on IIS got 404 errors on other URI than root

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-server-2012

I have an ASPNet core application that run correctly on IIS Express with Visual Studio.
I've tried to deploy this application on IIS Server 8.5 (With file folder). If I access to the root URI (/), my page appears correctly (Status 200). But if I try to access to other URI (ex: /Meetings), I get a 404 errors.
Another things, I have tried to change the identity of the application pool to administrator and it works. But I know that it's not the best practice and I can't find why it's not working with the app pool identity.
Below some configuration, ask me if you want specific file: 
web.config :

```
<configuration>

<!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
    <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Access logs :

```
2018-07-18 13:14:08 ::1 GET /Meetings - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/67.0.3396.99+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 0 1422
2018-07-18 13:22:54 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/67.0.3396.99+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 1841
```

App pool configuration : 
[image: App pool configuration]

I have also tried to change the permission to the folder, but not working.

If someone already had this problem, I'm ready to try different solutions.

Thanks,

EDIT :

Detail log of the 404 error here : https://paste.ee/p/4PBzY

EDIT 2 :

I have found this information in the windows events, but I have a connection string and my SQL Server is congured with local account.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found where was the problem.

After look at the event viewer, I saw that application try to connect to my SQL Server with the ApplicationPoolIdentity, as can you see on the screen below (sorry for the french screen) 
[image]

So, I have just add this user into SQL Server with permissions on my database and configure like Mohsin Mehmood advises me (see other answer), and now it works !
[image]

Comment: Great that you were able to figure out the issue

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the performed the following steps:

1. You need to publish your website and then point IIS website to the published folder
2. Application pool must be set to `No Managed code`
3. Application Pool identity user `IIS AppPool\{AppPoolName}` must have read permissions on the published website folder. Change the identity of your application pool to **ApplicationPoolIdentity**. For application pool identity there will be user account with name `IIS AppPool\{Applicaiton Pool name}` e.g. for DefaultAppPool the user account is `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` so you can allow read/write access to your to Applicaiton Pool user on published application folder

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked all of these steps, but still getting the same error (404 Not Found except on root path). I have also try to set RoomScheduling (Who is my application pool identity) as the owner of the folder but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked that Url-Rewrite extension is installed?

Comment: Yes, I have RewriteModule in the module's list (located as rewrite.dll)

Comment: In your web.config, try changing ` <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"` to
`<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\{yourdllname}.dll"`

Comment: I've try but doesn't work. This is strange because if I check the configuration, Authentication is ok but authorization is in warning. But if I change the AppPool identity to Administrator, authorization is ok and it works. But I have set permissions to AppPoolIdentity (IIS AppPool\RoomScheduling) to total control.

Comment: Just confirm that for your webapp the `Anonymous Auth` is enabled. Also, with your website selected in left pane, double click `Authentication` in right pane, then right click the `Anonymous Authentication` and then click `Edit`. Ensure that `Application Pool Identity` user is selected

Comment: Yes, Application Pool Identity is selected. I update my post with more details on the error